# PointCloud2 not organized

Tags: gazebo, urdf, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm reading PointCloud2 sensor messages from a robot in Gazebo. However, the point cloud given by the message is always unorganized (width=307200, height=1). In the urdf file, the size of the image is set to 640x480. Is there some way to guarantee organization?

At the moment, my code does the "reorganization" of the cloud manually (using a for loop).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98426/pointcloud2-not-organized/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2013-11-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It may not be supported. It's recommended to ask gazebo questions on answers.gazebosim.org

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2013-11-19**:
Manual reorganization of the point cloud seems to be working fine, and it is only a few lines of code.

**Comment by [itzsid](https://answers.ros.org/users/4570/itzsid/) on 2014-03-23**:
@atp, I am facing the same problem. How did you convert the unorganized point cloud to organized point cloud? Does the cloud follow row-major order?